# Getting local hour with NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

New to NodaTime and I chose to use it instead of the BCL libraries because it removes a lot of ambiguity when dealing with dates. However, I can't seem to get it to do what I want. I have a date and time specified by year, month, day, hours, and minutes. I also have two timezones for which I need to display the "clock time". For example, if my input is December 15, 2015 at 3:30 PM and my two timezones are central standard and eastern standard (one hour apart), I expect my output to be

```
12/15/2015 3:30 PM Central
12/15/2015 4:30 PM Eastern
```

But I can only seem to get the central (local to me, if that matters) timezone.  Here's my code:

```
var localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(
            year: 2015,
            month: 12,
            day: 15,
            hour: 15,
            minute: 30,
            second: 0
            );

var centralTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull("Central Standard Time");
var easternTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetZoneOrNull("Eastern Standard Time");

var centralTime = centralTimeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
var easternTime = easternTimeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
```

It seems that centralTime and easternTime are both ZonedDateTime objects whose times are 2015-12-10T15:30 with the correct offset i.e. centralTime is -6 and easternTime is -5.)

I just can't figure out how to get the output I want.

Comment: What are `memberTaskTime` and `userTaskTime`? Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? It's also not clear what you mean by "the clock time" - you're starting with a `LocalDateTime`, but what time zone is that meant to be in? It sounds like you're *really* starting with a Central time, in which case you probably want `var easternTime = centralTime.InZone(easternTimeZone)`.

Comment: Spot on. One time is user provided and the other is generated by the system. Using InZone is what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Righto - adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your initial date/time is actually in Central time - so once you've performed the initial conversion, you can just say "Hey, I want the same instant in time, but in a different time zone" - which isn't the same as "I want a different instant in time for the same *local* time". You want:

```
var centralTime = centralTimeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
var easternTime = centralTime.InZone(easternTimeZone);
```